# Pointwise convergence in $C(K)$ where $K$ is compact hausdorff

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, uniform-convergence

Let $ \{f_n\}$ be a sequence in $C(K)$ where $K$ is a compact Hausdorff space with $|f_n| \le 1$ for $n=1,2,......$ .  If $f \in C(K)$ and $ f_n \to f$ pointwise on $K$ then show that there exist some sequence of convex combinations of the $f_n$ 's converge uniformly to $f$.

I know that $C(K)$ in complete under sup norm.But I am unable solve this using the completeness..Need some help.

Comment: Do you know weak convergence and some real analysis?

Comment: Yes I know that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an overkill I guess. Let $\mu$ be a Radon measure on $X$, then $\mu(K) <\infty$. Also $\| f_n\|_{L^1}$ is uniformly bounded by $\mu(K)$ as $|f_n|\le 1$. By Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem, 
$$\tag{1} \int_K f_n d\mu \to \int_X f d\mu.$$
By Riesz' representation theorem, all bounded linear functional on $C(K)$ is given by Radon measure, thus $(1)$ implies that $\{f_n\}$ converges weakly to $f$. Now the claimed result follows from [Mazur's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mazur%27s_lemma), which claimed that if $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence in a Banach space $X$ which converges weakly in $X$ to $f$, then a convex combination of $\{f_n\}$ converges strongly to $f$ in $X$. Now our Banach space is $X = (C(K), \| \cdot \|_\infty)$, so the conclusion is that a convex combination of $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly to $f$.

Comment: Can you please explain why the result follows from Mazur's lemma? To me Mazur's lemma states that closure of a conves set is same in usual topology and in weak topology@John Ma

Comment: Thanks for the edit. But I know a different statement of Mazur's lemma

Comment: Then if $f_n$ converges to $f$ weakly, $f$ is in the weak closure of the convex combination of $\{f_1, f_2, \cdots\}$, which is a convex set. Then by your version it's in the strong closure. @Saikat